# Change the speed of games in Android / SpeedHack for Android

Tags: applications, performance

Is there a way to slow down / speed up the actual game speed? For Windows PC, there is the [Cheat Engine SpeedHack](http://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Cheat_Engine%3aSpeedhack) that does it nicely. Is there anything (requiring root or not) to achieve similar effect on Android?

Check the Cheat Engine wiki (linked above) for the description in the functionality.

Comment: Well, you can always flash a new kernel and use SetCPU to change your clockspeed, but this won't have quite the effect you're wanting. It'll just make the CPU faster/slower, which you'll only really notice with things like emulation (PlayStation, for example)

Comment: Any updates from your end?

Comment: Hy @geffchang thanks a lot for participating, but unfortunately no. I am gonna check some of the answers, but I just rage-quit the slowpoke of a strategy game that prompted me to ask this in the first place, so the need went away.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/download). It perfect works on all Android versions include Lollipop and Marshmallow.

It have speedhack worked on arm and x86 devices, include x86 emulators like Bluestacks, Droid4X, Andy and others.